# CiviCRM not recognizing bounces

Tags: email, bounce, bounce-processing, inbound-email

I tried sending emails using mass email which included wrong address. So CiviCRM was supposed to put those bad emails on bounces but it wasn't working.
I have already added an mail account for bounce handling in CiviCRM Mail Accounts and have enabled bounce processing for scheduled jobs.
How can i solve it ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have correctly added an mail account for bounce handling in CiviCRM Mail Accounts and have enabled bounce processing for scheduled jobs (you said you had so that bit was more to help others who find this answer) then I hope some of below helps

1. ensure the email account accepts ‘plus addressing’
2. go to your bounce inbox and confirm the email is there
3. confirm the email is not in you spam folder in that mail account
4. if it is in spam (or can't be found) then ensure that the email account being used has a rule set up to ensure this does not happen and/or that the settings for the account do not preclude spam from showing in the folders (from memory MS accounts have an 'upstream' setting that can affect access to the Junk folder)
5. check the log for the Fetch Bounce scheduled job
6. ensure the civicrm Mail Account settings are using the correction option for POP v IMAP etc
7. add more info to your Question about what type of mail account it is

Comment: Also have you set up your email system so that bounces are directed to the email account that you added to CiviMail?  (rather fundamental, but I've forgotten to do this).